# Jquery Ajax Post fails with sending html content

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
$("#btnSend").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url         : "/ControllerName/MethodName",
       type        : "POST",
       dataType    : "json",
       contentType : "application/html",
       data        : '{ divhtml:"<p>World</p>" }'

    });
});
```

Passes null to the action method. Tried to change the content type to json. Started giving errors. What's the proper way?

Comment: Can you put what errors are u getting.

Comment: With JSON, keys are supposed to enclosed in quotes. Don't hardcode the string either, use `JSON.stringify({key: value})`

Comment: Try using url: '@Url.Action("ControllerName", "ActionName")' and then let me know

Comment: @levi The error was: Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (58): { divhtml:"

Answer (score 1):

Change data: line. It should be. Without  ''.

```
$("#btnSend").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url         : "/ControllerName/MethodName",
       type        : "POST",
       dataType    : "json",
       contentType : "application/json",
       data        : { 'divhtml':"<p>World</p>" }

    });
});
```

Comment: Already went for stringify and sorted. But, I gave yours a try. Passing null. But it works if I change it to: data:"{ divhtml:'"<p>World</p>"' }", and contentType: "application/json".

Comment: May be because your response is in json and you were trying to catch a html ones. because that it may be worked when u changed it to: ontentType: "application/json"